# Node.js scope of a variable inside a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

I am just getting started with node.js, and on a small program I am writing I am running into a problem when trying to pass a variable.

I have a function which I pass a line I have read from a file. In that function create a Mongoose model of the line and try to save it to the database. That is working fine, however in cases where there is something wrong with the data and it can't be saved to the database I would like to save it to a text file.

I added a call to save to the file, the file gets created but is always empty. When debugging the code, The console messages are displayed and it appears that at that point in the execution line is an empty string. Is this the proper way to pass the value ?

```js
var parseRecord = function (line) {
    var arrayOfString = line.toString().split(" ");

    if (arrayOfString[0].substr(0,1) != '#'){
        var dbRecord = new LogEntry({
            logDateTime: arrayOfString[0] + ' ' + arrayOfString[1],
            serverIP: arrayOfString[2],
            requestMethod: arrayOfString[3],
            uriStem: arrayOfString[4],
            serverPort:arrayOfString[6],
            clientIP:arrayOfString[8],
            browserType:arrayOfString[9],
            referrerSite:arrayOfString[10],
            httpStatus:arrayOfString[11],
            bytesSent:arrayOfString[12],
            bytesReceived:arrayOfString[13],
            elapsedTime:arrayOfString[14]
        });

        dbRecord.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
//                console.log("Skipped one record");
//                console.log("This is the skipped line:" + bufferedLine);
                fs.appendFile('skippedRecords.txt', line, function (err) {
                    if (err)
                        console.log("Could not write skipped record");
                });
                //skippedRecords++;
            } else {
                //insertedRecords++;
            }
        })
        //dbRecord.print();
    }
}
```

Thank you for any suggestions. 
--MD

Comment: I don't see ```bufferedLine``` being defined anywhere.

Comment: Most likely `bufferedLine` should be `line`.

Comment: Yes, bufferedLine is line. I forgot to correct after I pasted the code here.

Comment: `line` is of type Buffer?

Comment: I am using a module called line-by-line [link] (https://www.npmjs.com/package/line-by-line) to read the file, line is the object returned by this event  'code' lr.on('line', function (line) {
    // 'line' contains the current line without the trailing newline character.
});

Comment: If you add `console.log(line); setTimeout(function() { console.log(line); }, 2000);` right inside your parseRecord function, does it log the right thing both times?

Comment: @tandrewnichols, I added in two places, right at the beginning and inside the dbRecord.save block. In the beginning shows the content of the line, inside the block shows an empty string.

Comment: Try the setTimeout version too. I'm just curious if it's a reference thing. It looks like, in line-by-line, the instance is reused over and over and the same field is set, so I'm wondering if it's getting blown away before you have a chance to write the error. I don't see any reason it would be related to scoping. I mean, it's in scope in both places, so _something_ is changing it's value.

Comment: You could also just try assigning line to a local variable to make sure it's not a reference to a memory location that changes. Just first thing inside parseRecord set `var ln = line.toString();`

Comment: And if you can't resolve why `line` is disappearing you could always just write `arrayOfString.join(' ')` to the file instead.

Comment: @tandrenichols I tried all 3 suggestions. I narrowed it down to something happening inside the if (err) block. Once it gets there, the value set on any variable is pretty much gone.